# Liar paradox from a different view/resolved?

Tags: logic, paradox

Informally,  the statement T: 
T: "this statement is not both true and not true" 
a) T is not true if and only if it is both true and not true
b) T is true if and only if it is not both true and not true

we can agree that:
 1. saying  of T that it is not true is equivalent to saying that it is both true and not true

2. Saying of T that it is true is equivalent  to saying that it is not both true and not true .

but T says about itself that it is not both true and not true, 
which is equivalent to T saying that it is either true or not true (in classical logic).
which is equivalent to T saying that it is EITHER not both true and not true OR both true and not true. 
Therefore T is equivalent to "this statement is true and not not true"  (truth teller sentence)
but then L:  "this statement is both true and not true" is equivalent to "this statement is not true" (Liar sentence)

T is necessarily true , therefore truth teller is necessarily true

L is necessarily not true , therefore liar sentence is necessarily not true.
Therefore there is no paradox.
Whats even more all this works with a formalized Liar sentence too ( e.g.
∃x(Qx & ~Tx), where Q and T are predicates which are satisfied by names of sentences. More specifically, T is the one-place, global truth predicate satisfied by all and only the names [that is, numerals for the Gödel numbers] of the true sentences, and Q is a one-place predicate that is satisfied only by the name of ∃x(Qx & ~Tx).)

Why is this solution not yet popular, it seems so obvious to me?

Comment: Not clear... You say that T is "statement T is **not** (TRUE and **not** TRUE)" that (by De Morgan) amounts to :  "statement T is (either **not** TRUE or TRUE)" which is not paradoxical.

Comment: Not every self-refernce leads to paradox : the gist of [Liar's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/) is that self-reference **may** produce paradoxes.

Comment: "Therefore T is equivalent to 'this statement is true and not not true'" It's not clear to me how this follows.

Comment: Because saying of T that it is not true is equivalent to saying of T that it is both true and not true , therefore saying of T that it is not both true and not true is equivalent to saying of T that it is not both (true) and (both true and not true) , therefore it is equivalent to saying of T that it is true and not both true and not true ,therefore it is equivalent to saying of T that is true and not not true. well T says about itself that it is not both true and not true , via these equivalences it says "this statement is true and not not true"

Comment: Your statement L is simply false, as you point out - it is not true that "this statement is both true and not true". But that's not the liar paradox, which tries to assign a truth value to "this statement is not true". Statement L and the liar paradox statement aren't equivalent, so it's not clear how you attempt to resolve the paradox by making inferences about L (in which there is no paradox).

Answer (score 1):

Your identification of the *classical liar*

> L: "L is false"

and the *modified liar*

> M: "M is false and M is true"

is flawed.

Let's say for simplicity that we agree that for each sentence P we should have the equivalence "P iff [(P) and (P is true)]." Even granting this, we have to be careful about *scope* here, specifically with regards to what happens inside and outside of the original sentence.

That is, for an arbitrary sentence P let [P] be the sentence "P is true." Then our equivalence *does* tell us that L is equivalent to the conjunction

> C: "(L: L is false) and [L],"

but you want to bring the conjunction *inside* the name binding to get (after appropriate renaming) an equivalence between our original L and the new sentence

> L': "L' is false and [L']."

This may seem benign at first, but it needs to be carefully justified. For example, consider the following three sentences:

> X: "X has four words."

> Y: "X has four words and X is true."

> Z: "Z has four words and Z is true."

Whether or not we regard X and Y as "the same," they're each clearly true while Z is clearly false. Similarly, exactly the fact that L' is unproblematic while L is quite problematic should indicate that there is something serious going on here.

So at this point you really need to fall back on some precise theory of logic-with-truth-predicates. Indeed, we really should have done that *earlier*, since right off the bat substitution in the context of naming and self-reference pose interesting *syntactic* issues which need to be addressed before things can even be appropriately formulated.

(Now that's not to say that there's nothing interesting here. In some sense you're isolating a "deflation operator" here, where we replace a sentence "P: [...]" with its deflated version "P': ... and P' is true)" *(where "..." is the result of replacing each "P" in [...] with "P'")*. You might now try to claim that only "fully deflated" sentences, that is, sentences which are "easily provably equivalent" to their own deflations, are actually meaningful, and this does indeed forbid the classical liar. But this is a **serious** semantic commitment, requiring justification, and one which I think many people would actually *disagree* with (myself included).)

Comment: Um hi! I object to your claim that for every sentence P we should have ( P iff True(P) ). This only holds if we have already justified that P is a sentence with boolean truth-value. Clearly, these 'paradoxes' do not involve such boolean sentences, so we do not have this equivalence.

Answer (score -1):

Idk if my argument below corresponds to yours but let's say

A. B is true.
B. A is false.

If you interpret these disquotationwise, they "turn into" (A. A is false) and (B. B is true), which looks like something you wrote? Good question and proposal, at any rate.

Comment: But in this way it is a simple variant of the usual [Liar's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/#LiarCycl). So what ?

Comment: The idea, or at least my take on it, is that this shows the liar and the honest sentences to somehow be equivalent, which supports Tarski's levels-of-truth image, where "true" and "false" inside the L and H sentences are different enough from "true" and "false" outside them, that combining them doesn't yield the required contradiction.